# Display the sum of all raised odd and even number using loop and control structures

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, formula, control-structure

I need to create a java program that will accepts 10 integers and if the entered number is odd raise it to ^ 1 power and if the user input another odd number raised it again to the next power ^ 2, same with Even numbers however the power starts at 10 and will decrease in each even numbers inputed. After that, I have to display the sum of all Even and Odd numbers that was raised.

The hard thing is were not allowed to use arrays, and java.util.Math.

For example:

The program ask the user to input 10 integers:

User inputted ( integers 1-10 ):

1 ^ 1 = 1 (odd)

2 ^ 10 = 1024 (even)

3 ^ 2 = 9 (odd)

4 ^ 9 = 262 114 (even)

5 ^ 3 = 125 (odd)

6 ^ 8 = 1 679 616 (even)

7 ^ 4 = 2 401 (odd)

8 ^ 7 = 2 097 152 (even)

9 ^ 5 = 59 049 (odd)

10 ^ 6 = 1 000 000 (even)

Output:
The sum of Even Powered

The sum of Odd Powered

Thanks Devon, I tried to run the program but i have logical error.

```
public class SumOfOddEvenMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SumOfOddEven temp = new SumOfOddEven();
    System.out.println(temp.Run());
}
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfOddEven {
private long sumOfOdds;
private long sumOfEvens;
private int countOfOdds;
private int countOfEvens;

public SumOfOddEven() {
    countOfOdds = 1;
    countOfEvens = 10;
    sumOfOdds = 0;
    sumOfEvens = 0;
}
public String Run() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter integer number " + i);
        int number = in.nextInt();

        if(number % 2 == 0) {
            for(int j = countOfEvens; j > 1; j--) {
                number *= number;
            }

            sumOfEvens += number;
            countOfEvens--;
        }
        else {
            for(int k = countOfOdds; k > 1; k--) {
                number *= number;
            }

            sumOfOdds += number;
            countOfOdds++;
        }
    }

    in.close();
    return "Sum of odds: " + sumOfOdds + "\nSum of evens: " + sumOfEvens;
}
```

}

Program Output:

```
Enter integer number 0
1
Enter integer number 1
2
Enter integer number 2
3
Enter integer number 3
4
Enter integer number 4
5
Enter integer number 5
6
Enter integer number 6
7
Enter integer number 7
8
Enter integer number 8
9
Enter integer number 9
10
Sum of odds: -495568963
Sum of evens: 0
```

Comment: Please post what code you have written to solve this problem, and what issue(s) you are having with it.

Comment: "_... not allowed to use arrays, and java.util.Math_": not a problem (:-)).  You can get by without either of those.  What about this assignment are you having the most trouble with?

Comment: yeah, our instructor said to use float if we encounter error with int. Int max value = 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfOddEven {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sumOddInts = 0, sumEvenInts = 0, countOddInts = 1, countEvenInts = 10;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Count: " + i + ", enter an integer (from 1 to 10): ");
            int number;
            do {
                number = in.nextInt();
                if (!(number >= 0 && number <= 10)) {
                    System.out.println("Try again, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): ");
                } else {
                    if (number % 2 == 0) {
                        sumEvenInts += power(number, countEvenInts--);
                    } else {
                        sumOddInts += power(number, countOddInts++);
                    }
                }
            } while (!(number >= 0 && number <= 10));
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("The sum of even powered: " + sumEvenInts);
        System.out.println("The sum of odd powered: " + sumOddInts);
    }

    static int power(int n, int power) {
        int num = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
            num *= n;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

**Note**: The program given above restricts the numbers, being raised to the power as per the requirement, to 1 to 10 to avoid integer overflow

**A sample run:**

```
Count: 1, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
12
Try again, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
3
Count: 2, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
5
Count: 3, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
6
Count: 4, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
7
Count: 5, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
8
Count: 6, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
2
Count: 7, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
1
Count: 8, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
9
Count: 9, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
10
Count: 10, enter an integer (from 1 to 10): 
4
The sum of even powered: 204688256
The sum of odd powered: 59421
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SumOfOddEven {
    private long sumOfOdds;
    private long sumOfEvens;
    private int countOfOdds;
    private int countOfEvens;

    public SumOfOddEven() {
        countOfOdds = 1;
        countOfEvens = 10;
        sumOfOdds = 0;
        sumOfEvens = 0;
    }
    public String Run() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter integer number " + i);
            long number = in.nextLong();

            if(number % 2 == 0) {
                for(int j = countOfEvens; j >= 1; j--) {
                    number *= number;
                }

                sumOfEvens += number; 
                countOfEvens--;
            }
            else {
                for(int k = countOfOdds; k >= 1; k--) {
                    number *= number;
                }

                sumOfOdds += number;
                countOfOdds++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return "Sum of odds: " + sumOfOdds + "\nSum of evens: " + sumOfEvens; 
    }

}
```

And then in the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SumOfOddEven temp = new SumOfOddEven();
    System.out.println(temp.Run());
}
```

You can do checking to make sure the input is valid as well with a simple condition to see if the input is an integer or any other stipulation that the assignment says to check for. If that condition is true, then simply have Run() call itself again and reset the count variables.

Comment: Thanks devon, currently i'm having the following error: Error:(16, 59) java: int cannot be dereferenced

 on this >>>           System.out.println("Enter integer number " + i.toString());

Comment: Take out the .toString() on that line.

Comment: Let me know if that worked. I wrote this without testing it so I think it should work but don't know for sure..

Comment: I remove the toString() in System.out.println("Enter integer number " + i.toString());

Run the program ( inputted integers 1 - 10) and I got the output:

SumOdds 5
SumEven 0

Comment: try making the k and j variables in the for loops to do k-- and j-- instead of k++ and j++.

Comment: hello devon, i change it to k-- and j-- and the outputs where:
SumOdds -495568963
SumEven 0

Should i change the int to float? btw, thank you i've been trying to solve this problem. It's hard without array and math class.

Comment: You can debug and see what the variables values are when going through the Run method. Otherwise from reading it alone, I can't see the problem but I might figure it out. If I could debug it I'm sure I'd find it quicker but I don't have anything to run java code at the moment.

Comment: Try adding the in.close() that I just added maybe that's causing weird things since before we didn't close the Scanner.

Comment: i tried adding in.close() but the output was:
Sum of odds: -495568963
Sum of evens: 0

Thanks devon for your help, i might as well give up. Im not sure if our instructor has the solution, because i think he just made this up...

Comment: This is very possible. Do you know how to debug? If so, check what value the variables are during the run method by adding a breakpoint in the method.

Comment: I'm guessing when the sums get too large that they are overflowing... try making them long instead of ints. so long sumOfEven instead of int sumOfEven.

Comment: I don't know how to debug. We never tried it before. I gone ahead and change them to floats. Outputs where: 
Sum of odds: -4.9556896E8
Sum of evens: 0.0

Comment: change them to long I meant sorry

Comment: No need to apologize, I should be thankful for your help. I change it to long im still having output :
Sum of odds: -495568963
Sum of evens: 0

Comment: Please take your time Devon,

I'm really having a hard time with this, that's why i want to know how to solve this. The harder the problem the more I learn.

 thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm impatient with myself not you I should know this lol. It still looks like overflow which is strange. Do you understand how the flow of the code that I wrote works though? As that is the most important part.

Comment: try making each variable long except for the counts. Like number has to be long since we are doing operations with it and setting them to our long variables. When we assign number (as an int) to a long, the long is set = to the integer value.

Comment: and do .nextLong() instead of .nextInt()

Comment: You would need to use a massive data type to figure this one out. I would look into the use of BigInteger. I'm not sure how it works but there are questions about it on Stackoverflow already. Good luck!